# Preferred way to do locales in the Haskell Platform

Tags: haskell, localization, internationalization, haskell-platform

The Haskell platform includes two obsolete libraries, `old-time` and `old-locale`. For old-time, it also includes the preferred alternative (namely `time`), but I can't figure out what the recommended alternative for `old-locale` is.

Is this simply a shortcoming of the Platform as of now (version 2010.1.0.0), or something I've overlooked?

Answer (score 11):

The libraries in the HP are by definition not obsolete. The particular names used though, are up to the maintainers. old-locale remains the preferred mechanism for manipulating locales.

Comment: Well, the Hackage description (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/old-locale-1.0.0.2 ) says: "This package provides the old locale library. For new code, the new locale library is recommended." If that's not an explicit deprecation, I don't know what is.

Comment: @user355466 sadly that is just wishful thinking. The "new" locale lib is clearly stalled. I've not seen any discussion of a replacement for some time.

Comment: It's not possible to merge stalles new locale lib into old-locale and rename old-locale too new-locale?

Answer (score 2):

In **old-locale-1.0.0.5**, the deprecation notice is removed: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/old-locale.

Comment: I'm sorry @Obs, the down vote was a complete accident!  I intended to up-vote, but didn't notice the mistake until it was "locked in."

Comment: Don't worry about it. :)